# Find charge per unit length of conductors

Tags: charge

Sorry if off-topic but I have a question in electrostatics. I didn't get any usefull answer at physics forums. The problem states:

Three very long (theoretically infinite long) hollow cylindrical conductors, with radius ***a,b,c,(c>b>a)*** are in vacuum. Inner and central conductor are charged, and outer conductor is grounded.  Potentials of inner and central conductors with reference point relative to outer conductor are ***Va,Vb***. Find charge per unit length of all three conductors.

[image]

I used Gauss's law to find electric field of one cylindrical conductor, which is $$E=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi r \epsilon_0}$$ Derivation of ***Va*** gives $$V_a=\int_a^b \frac{\lambda_a}{2\pi r \epsilon_0}dr+\int_b^c \frac{\lambda_a}{2\pi r \epsilon_0}dr=\frac{\lambda_a}{2\pi  \epsilon_0}\left(ln\frac{b}{a}+ln\frac{c}{b}\right)$$ Derivation of ***Vb*** gives $$V_b=\int_b^c \frac{\lambda_b}{2\pi \epsilon_0 r}dr=\frac{\lambda_b}{2\pi\epsilon_0}ln\frac{c}{b}$$ Now, charges per unit length for first two conductors are $$\lambda_a=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0 V_a}{ln\frac{b}{a}+ln\frac{c}{b}}$$ $$\lambda_b=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0 V_b}{ln\frac{c}{b}}$$ Using superposition, charge per unit length of third conductor is $$\lambda_c=\lambda_a+\lambda_b$$ Could someone check if this is correct? I am not sure if the limits of integration for potentials are right.

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question...

Let's start with your last statement. It must be

$$\lambda_c=-(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)$$

because cylinder C has to cancel out the charges of cylinders A and B.

Now, think about the fields generated by the three charges. It looks like this:

[image]

Remember, that the charge on a conducting,  hollow body does not generate any E-field inside.
But the E-field of a charge inside a hollow body does not end at the surface, it expands to infinity.
This also is a result of Gauß' law, as it simply says that *field times (closed) surface is charge inside that surface*.

The superposition of all fields is the grey curve, and now you see that

$$V_b=\int_b^c\frac{(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)}{2\pi\varepsilon_0r}\,dr$$

and

$$V_a=\int_a^b\frac{\lambda_a}{2\pi\varepsilon_0r}\,dr+V_b$$

With given potential(difference)s, you can calculate \$\lambda_a\$ and \$\lambda_b\$.